# Gerar querysets a partir de regras geradas dinamicamente

Tags: python, django

gostaria de fazer uma especie de filtro usando o Django.
Imaginem o seguinte caso:

- Model: usuário (Nome, sexo, idade, dia_nasciemnto, mes_nascimento, etc)
- Regra: Pegar todos os usuários com **Sexo=M** e **Idade>20**

A intenção seria gerar regras a partir de uma Aplicação e essas regras seriam vários **E** e **OU** encadeados. Se alguém puder me dar um norte ou contar como resolveu um problema parecido com esse e ficaria muito agradecido.

Comment: A sua pergunta está abrangente demais, perguntas abrangentes e/ou vagas conseguirão respostas do mesmo tipo, sendo assim acho que a resposta do @Gregory já é suficiente. O ideal seria que vc apresentasse algum código e mostrasse onde está a dúvida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar os objects Q() para compor sua querysets dinamicamente (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q)

Eu escrevi no meu blog do Medium um tutorial ilustrando como compor essas queries dinamicas, elas inclusive são mais rapidas e seguras (evitam race conditions) que o filter() nativo do Django.

https://medium.com/@csantosmachado/compondo-querysets-no-django-utilizando-objetos-q-c88bc3f65031

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado. Otimo trabalho ajudando a comunidade ! voce pode me mandar seu contato pra gente trocar ideia ?

Comment: @Gabriel pode me procurar no facebook, na comunidade do Python Brasil, sou administrador de lá. =)

Answer (score 3):

Da uma olhada no Django Filters. E super poderoso, ja tem comportamentos padroes que acho q vao te atender, mas coce tbm pode criar suas proprias classes filters e dentro delas implementar as suas regras
http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filters.html